# Why is webGl slow in my browser?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser

Most people say webGl is not slow, but it is really slow in my browsers IE 11, and Google Chrome 37.
I have also suddenly that almost all WebGL applications on the Internet does not work in google chrome anymore. I didn't change anything on my computer. I think it's an update or something.
Each time when I visit a webGl application, the site says that webGl is not supported. But when i create a little simple webGl app by myself and visit it with Google Chrome, it starts correctly.
But I've always had that WebGL so slow is that there's nothing you have.
What can I do to fix my Chrome problem? And are there any solutions to increate speed?

Comment: Install new graphics card drivers?

Comment: How can I do that? Is this a common problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. 
it is necessary that WebGL supported sites also support browsers. as you said some sites are not working properly in google chrome and IE it is only because sites doesn't have support for that browser any more, vice versa is also true.
it is undergoing development when they don't support each other, this type of problem arise.